Get the Potential of a Vector Field by Integration
I have given the following exercise:
For the potential $\Phi$ of a vector field $\vec{F}$, the following holds:
$\vec{F} = \nabla \Phi$
Determine one potential $\Phi$ for the following field:
$\vec{F} = (x + 2y + 4z)\hat{e}_x + (2x - 3y - z)\hat{e}_y + (4x - y + 2z)\hat{e}_z$
Question:
I have a solution stating that the potential is
$$\frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{3}{2}y^2 + z^2 + C $$
However, if I integrate all the components $(x,y,z)$ of $\vec{F}$ I end up with the following three equations:
$$ - ( \frac{x^2}{2} + 2xy + 4xz + f_1(y,z) )$$
$$ - (2xy - \frac{3}{2} y^2 - zy + f_2(x,z) ) $$
$$ - (4xz - yz +z^2 +f_3(x,y) ) $$
when I then compare these equations I can determine the functions $f_i$
Then I end up with
$$\phi(x,y,z)= -\frac{x^2}{2} -2xy -4xz + \frac{3}{2} y^2 +zy -z^2 + C $$
where $C$ is the integration constant.
I mean when I then test "backwards" so to speak $\nabla \phi $ I get the correct $\vec{F}$ but not with the given solution in my class. However, since it is an official solution, I am confused.
I do not understand where I went wrong and would appreciate any help! :)

Use  WA to double check your solution.  There might be a sign error. The other potential (form class?)  is clearly wrong.

The technique followed is into the book "Analisi matematica 2" by Marco Bramanti, Carlo Domenico Pagani, and Sandro Salsa, published by Zanichelli Editore.

The vector field is given by:
$$
\mathbf{F} = (x + 2y + 4z)\hat{\mathbf{x}} + (2x - 3y - z)\hat{\mathbf{y}} + (4x - y + 2z)\hat{\mathbf{z}}.
$$
To find the potential $\Phi$, we use the relationship $\mathbf{F} = -\boldsymbol\nabla \Phi$, which leads to the following conditions:
$$
\Phi_x = -(x + 2y + 4z), \
\Phi_y = -(2x - 3y - z), \
\Phi_z = -(4x - y + 2z).
$$
From $\Phi_x = -(x + 2y + 4z)$, integrating with respect to $x$, we get:
$$
\Phi = -\frac{x^2}{2} - 2xy - 4xz + f(y, z),
$$
where $f(y, z)$ is an arbitrary function of $y$ and $z$.
Next, from $\Phi_y = -(2x - 3y - z)$, we differentiate with respect to $y$ and match the terms:
$$
-2x - \frac{\partial f(y, z)}{\partial y} = -(2x - 3y - z),
$$
which gives:
$$
\frac{\partial f(y, z)}{\partial y} = 3y + z.
$$
Integrating with respect to $y$, we obtain:
$$
f(y, z) = \frac{3y^2}{2} + yz + g(z),
$$
where $g(z)$ is an arbitrary function of $z$. Finally, from $\Phi_z = -(4x - y + 2z)$, differentiating with respect to $z$ and matching the terms:
$$
-4x - \frac{\partial f(y, z)}{\partial z} = -(4x - y + 2z),
$$
we get:
$$
\frac{\partial g(z)}{\partial z} = -2z.
$$
Integrating with respect to $z$, we find:
$$
g(z) = -z^2 + C,
$$
where $C \in \mathbb{R}$ is a constant. Thus, the potential $\Phi$ is:
$$
\Phi(x, y, z) = -\frac{x^2}{2} - 2xy - 4xz + \frac{3y^2}{2} + yz - z^2 + C.
$$

Parametrize a path from $(0,0,0)$ to $(x,y,z)$ via three line segments. First, let $\mathbf{r}(t)=(t,0,0)$ for $t\in[0,x]$ with $\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}=(1,0,0)\,\mathrm{d}t$. Then $\mathbf{F}(t,0,0)=(t,2t,4t)$. Its dot product with $\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}$ is $t\,\mathrm{d}t$. Integration from $0$ to $x$ yields $x^2/2$. Next, let $\mathbf{r}(t)=(x,t,0)$ for $t\in[0,y]$ with $\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}=(0,1,0)\,\mathrm{d}t$. Then $\mathbf{F}(x,t,0)=(x+2t,\,2x-3t,\,4x-t)$. Its dot product with $\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}$ is $2x-3t$. Integration from $0$ to $y$ yields $2xy - \tfrac{3y^2}{2}$. Finally, let $\mathbf{r}(t)=(x,y,t)$ for $t\in[0,z]$ with $\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}=(0,0,1)\,\mathrm{d}t$. Then $\mathbf{F}(x,y,t)=(x+2y+4t,\,2x-3y-t,\,4x-y+2t)$. Its dot product with $\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}$ is $4x - y + 2t$. Integration from $0$ to $z$ yields $4xz - yz + z^2$. Summing all contributions and adding an arbitrary constant $C$ gives
$$\Phi(x,y,z) \;=\;\frac{x^2}{2}\;+\;2xy\;+\;4xz\;-\;\frac{3y^2}{2}\;-\;yz\;+\;z^2\;+\;C.$$
Differentiating confirms $\nabla \Phi=\mathbf{F}$, so this is a valid potential.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
